# Eclipse RCP with Gradle - bnd instruction Import-Package not working for org.eclipse.e4.core.di

Tags: eclipse, gradle, osgi, bnd, bndtools

I have an Eclipse RCP, dependencies managed with gradle.

After updating to a newer Eclipse version with Java 11 I'm currently updating the dependencies. That's when I've encountered a problem.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.8.200.v20220512-1957

and saw that the Manifest of org.eclipse.e4.core.di doesn't import javax.annotation anymore:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.5.2
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
Bundle-Version: 1.8.200.v20220512-1957
Bundle-Name: %pluginName
Bundle-Vendor: %providerName
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-11
Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.di;version="1.7.0",org.eclipse.e4.co
 re.di.suppliers;version="1.7.0",org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di;x-frien
 ds:="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts",org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.osgi
 ;x-internal:=true,org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.shared;x-friends:="or
 g.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier"
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations;bundle-version="[1.4.
 0,2.0.0)";visibility:=reexport,javax.annotation;bundle-version="[1.3.5,
 2.0.0)"
Import-Package: javax.inject;version="1.0.0",org.eclipse.osgi.framework.
 log;version="1.1.0",org.osgi.framework;version="1.8.0",org.osgi.util.tr
 acker;version="1.5.1"
```

So naturally I've tried using bnd tools to include javax.annotation in the Import-Packages:

```
bnd group: 'org.eclipse.platform', name: 'org.eclipse.e4.core.di', {
        instruction 'Import-Package', 'javax.annotation, *'
        instruction '-noee', 'true'
    }
```

but no matter what I try to do (and I've tried a lot of things), the Manifest never gets edited... I've also tried omitting the group definition, tried including the version, but nothing seems to have any effect on the Manifest.

On the other hand I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track. For other dependecies I was successful with this approach but maybe this is all wrong?

Comment: Maybe because it already has a `Require-Bundle` for javax.annotion. Note that the current version of Eclipse changes this again to use `Import-Package`

Comment: Hi @greg-449 thanks for the reply :) the current version meaning Java 17?  We need Java 11. And I also thought that maybe Require-Bundle might already be sufficient but what else could cause the exception during startup then? For a different problem it helped to include the dep in Import-Package even when it was already in Require-Bundle...

Comment: I mean the Eclipse current version - 2023-09, you are using 2022-06. But the current release does need Java 17. Note that Java 11 is end of life this month. Java 21 is the current LTS Java. I can't answer questions about gradle builds, I use the recommended [tag:tycho]

Comment: yeah we have to use Java 11 sadly, but thanks for your kind anwers